# How to add retweet and favorite buttons using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter

I have made a code in javascript/jquery which populates a division with tweets of a specific handle.

```
$.getJSON("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name="+ handle + "&count=" + noOfTweets + "&include_rts=true&callback=?", function(data) {
    //some code
});
```

Here is the code to display the tweets

```
Json.parse(data);
$.each(data, function(i, tweet) {
  var buttonString = '<br/><a onclick="retweet('+tweet.id+')">Retweet</a>'
                            +'<a onclick="favorite('+tweet.id+')">Favorite</a>';

  $("#tweets").append($("<li/>").html(tweet.text+" <span class='tweetTime'>--a moment ago.</span>")+buttonString);
}
```

I now want to add retweet and favorite buttons to the tweets.
The twitter api for the above functions require a post request, but jquery doesn't have any .postJSON() function
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/retweet/:id
and
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/favorites/create/:id

so what should my retweet and favorite functions contain?
Some help please.

Comment: Used web intents instead.

can anyone say how can i make the buttons of a tweet appear/disappear on hover of that particular tweet?

Comment: Used onclick instead as if buttons were displayed on hover, how will i click them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery has a function to make POST requests - [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: I know that, but my query is related with how can i make a specific JSON request

Comment: You would pass the JSON string in the `data` attribute. POST variables are just strings, it's up to the receiving end to process it as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Used web intents instead.
Not preferable, but not bad.